# How to avoid Linking verbs flagging up as Passive

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

Example sentences:

The place was deserted.

The cars were red.

My grammar checker keeps flagging up linking verbs (was / were) as passive. How am I supposed to rewrite it?

(I suspect it's not a major grammar problem and that I can ignore this).

Comment: It's a major problem with your grammar checker. Can't you turn it off?

Comment: Ignore your grammar checker. There's nothing wrong with the passive anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some ways, linking verbs are passive. For example:
"I am frightened" has a linking verb, 'am', and an adjective, 'frightened'.
"I am frightened by the unknown" uses the passive voice of the verb 'to frighten'.
The question you should really be asking about anything flagged as 'passive' is whether you have chosen the best subject for the idea you want to express. The passive voice has a legitimate place! Which is more important in these two sentences, the lion or the man?
(a) "The lion ate the man."
(b) "The man was eaten by the lion."
If your focus is on the man, then the passive sentence (b) is the one you should probably prefer.

Comment: The passive has been covered in depth before on ELU, including advice on when it is best used and why. As has the ambiguity of sentences like 'The window was broken.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth way to go to encourage and helpfully guide newcomers to be part of the team! Yay! Comment, yes. Disagree, yes, DV because a newcomer doesn't know that the passive has been discussed to death on EL&U seems excessive.

Comment: Edwin's advice about the grammar checker  is valid, and I accept it. And I find the point Ross makes, "the best subject for the idea," useful.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I might have left it alone if you had flagged as a duplicate to begin with - in addition to your snide remark about grammar checkers.

Comment: It would help if people would check for duplicates themselves where there is a likelihood that such a topic has already been covered in the 90 000+ questions here already. I almost always check when I submit an answer (there are times when a search would take a ridiculous amount of time). Perhaps it's the people who spend a lot of time trying to maintain the credibility and trimness of the site who should be encouraged, @Mari-Lou A.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth all very well, but Ross has been a member for only 8 days. Give the newbie some slack, dude :) (Did I say that right?)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, thanks, and I notice the DV has been reversed. :)  I can see the point Edwin is making. This newbie has decided - given I definitely will not be bothered searching for whether new questions are duplicates - I should at least wait an hour or so before jumping in with an answer whenever it seems likely a question is a duplicate.

Comment: Your rapid accumulation of rep misled me, Ross. That's a wise course of action (though you have to be careful someone doesn't jump in with the answer you have). 'When it seems likely a new question will be a duplicate' [adjusted] takes some thought. Looking back through old questions can be very informative on various levels. For instance, influence of register (eg scientific) on choice of mood, different types of passive, the get-passive ... have all been covered. There has even been a debate over whether 'link verbs' is an acceptable term. // 'Can't you turn it off?' was a serious question.